# Is it possible to "flag" a user?

Tags: discussion, flagging, user-accounts

I know that the answer for a normal user is **not**.

What can be done?

Comment: Thanks for reporting that. I removed the user account as it was clearly only for spam. Please always flag posts like the one by this user as spam. This will autmatically add a system down-vote and the post will automatically be deleted and looked once it gets enough spam flags.

Comment: @MartinScharrer When I came into this user's account, his answer was already deleted. Seeing that the user account was still there, I didn't know how to point it out.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no way this can be done by users, since it may be a very subjective approach to moderation which is not visible to other users. Instead, it is suggested to either flag the users' posts or comments - anything that would get the attention of a moderator - and explain the situation.

Also see: [Flag abusive users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1323/168244)

Comment: I'd add: When you see spam, down-vote it always, too. Posts with a large negative score get automatically deleted and mods is warned.

Comment: I knew that a normal user **can not** do that. I was wondering whether it suffices only one moderator for deleting a user profile. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @tohecz I'm used to "flag" an answer/question when I see something like that, but see my reply to Martin's comment.

Comment: @karlkoeller Actually, a user can be IP-banned even without a mod performing any action, if he gets a lot of strong negative feedback. I'm not sure on which all sites this works though.

Comment: @tohecz In fact, if a post is spam, it suffices to flag it as spam. As Martin Scharrer explained, the post will automatically be deleted after a certain number of flags. A spam flag results in a down-vote that doesn’t count towards your personal downvotes (⇒ good for the flagger). Only getting a lot of downvotes won’t automatically delete a post, but chances are a mod will notice.